# Whats the POCO Equivalent of ACE/ActivationQueue?

Tags: c++, poco, message-queue, ace

Is [Poco::NotificationQueue](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.NotificationQueue.html) the same as [ACE/ActivationQueue](http://www.riverace.com/ACE/ace55/html/ace/classACE__Activation__Queue.html)?